# Camera is not dismiss after get barcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, barcode

I am using this class of `AVFoundation framework` to scan bar code

```
AVCaptureSession *_session;
AVCaptureDevice *_device;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *_input;
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *_output;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *_prevLayer;
```

My problem is that when I get bar code successfully then my camera view is not dismissed he stay open, can you tell me when I get bar code my camera should be dismiss, this in my code to get bar code.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)
metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
    NSString *detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
                detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (detectionString != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",detectionString);
            txt_cardSerialNumber.text = detectionString;
            break;
        }
        else
            _label.text = @"(none)";
    }

    _highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
}
```